# Switching text case with package collcell

Tags: capitalization, tabu, letterspacing, collcell

I would like to use the package `collcell` to change the case of every string in a column of a `tabu`environment. I know there are workarounds to do this without resorting to the package, but none of those I know seem quite "elegant" to me. Is it possible to do this in a more direct way by resorting to that package? I have tried with the following MWE but I get an error message.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{tabu,collcell}

\newcommand{\makeupper}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\newcolumntype{U}{>{\collectcell\makeupper}X[-1,r]<{\endcollectcell}}
\tabucolumn U

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tabu} spread0pt{@{}U@{}}
    Title \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

I would also like to use the package `soul` for letterspacing, but this comes only after having solved this first issue.

Comment: You should consider `microtype` for letter spacing.

Comment: Dear egreg, thanks so much. I'm used to the `soul` package, but I understand that the package `microtype` is more powerful than the former even regarding letterspacing for assorted pieces of text. Hence, in the near future I will most likely do as you suggest.

Comment: A *real* example would be useful for suggesting maybe better strategies.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. My only issue is how to make the strings uppercase in a column of a tabular environment in a simple way, and `collcell` seems to provide an elegant tool to do so, but it doesn't seem to work with something like `\MakeUppercase`.

Comment: `X` columns do paragraphs and `\MakeUppercase` doesn't like them. That's why I asked for a *real* example.

Comment: Alright, I had overlooked that point about X columns. My MWE is "for real" in that it is a minimal excerpt of what I am trying to achieve. I could use a different tabbing environment, but `tabu` provides for all my needs in a straightforward way. No hope to have a simple solution with X columns?

Comment: If you use `X[-1,m,p]` you code seems to work just fine.

Comment: Dear Peter, thanks for your attention. Your proposal works fine indeed, even with the joint processing comprised of switching to uppercase and letterspacing. Why it does is to me yet another of those LaTeX mysteries (maybe this state of affairs will change when once have `LaTeX3`). Nonetheless, I'd like to have the column ragged right. Anyone sees a possibility for this?

Comment: Ooops, sorry; please do read "ragged left" where I said "ragged right".

Comment: @PeterGrill Would you turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `X[-1,m,p]` your code seems to work just fine and the case is switched to upper case as desired:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{tabu,collcell}

\newcommand{\makeupper}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\newcolumntype{U}{>{\collectcell\makeupper}X[-1,m,p]<{\endcollectcell}}
\tabucolumn U

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tabu} spread0pt{@{}U@{}}
    Title \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```